# How do you fix upside-down camera?

Tags: rawbots

I seem to have somehow inverted the camera part on my rawbot.  Now when I enter first-person, my view is upside down:

[image: Upside down view]

No matter how I try detaching and reattaching the top block and the camera, my view is always upside down now when facing forward (It's upright if I put it on backwards).  I've even tried flipping the bot.  How can I fix this?

Comment: I *have* managed to fix it, but I don't think I could do it again reliably.  I took it apart and put it back together a bunch of times and it's upright now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rotating the camera with the right mouse button before plugging it in.